# Scripting sleep and wake up

Tags: macos, mac, script, sleep

I have an iMac that when it boots up the screen is all red and fuzzy, but if you put the Mac to sleep and wake it up again the screen is normal.

1. Has anyone had this issue? If so what is it?
2. I am looking for a sleep and wake up script so the Mac will load the script automaticaly once it has got the user select screen.

Any info would be great.

Answer (score 0):

A mac I had would have graphical problems similar to what you're describing when the logic board was going out. So that might be the answer to your first question.

That being said, the problem on mine wasn't only when the machine booted up.